# Linked list error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am building a doubly linked list with sentinel nodes in Python. I'm working on a method called remove_element_at that removes a node with a specified index and returns the value of that node. I keep getting the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' and I don't know why.

The method works for indexes 0 and 1 but nothing greater than that for some reason. Here is what I've written so far, the remove_element_at method is at the bottom.

````
class Linked_List:
    
    class __Node:
        
        def __init__ (self, val):
            self.val = val
            self.next = None
            self.prev = None 
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__size = 0
        self.__header = self.__Node(None)
        self.__trailer = self.__Node(None)
        self.__header.next = self.__trailer
        self.__trailer.prev = self.__header 
        self.__trailer.next = None
        self.__header.prev = None
        
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.__size
    
    def append_element(self, val):
        newest = Node(val)
        self.__trailer.prev.next = newest
        self.__trailer.prev = newest
        self.__size += 1
        
    def insert_element_at(self, val, index):
        if index < 0 or index >= self.__size:
            raise IndexError
        new_node = Node(val)
        current = self.__header.next
        prev = self.__header
        for i in range(index):
            if current is None:
                raise IndexError
            prev = current
            current = current.next
        new_node.next = current
        new_node.prev = prev
        prev.next = new_node
        if current is not None:
            current.prev = new_node
        self.__size += 1
        
    def remove_element_at(self, index):
        if index < 0 or index >= self.__size:
            raise IndexError
        current = self.__header.next
        for i in range(index):
            current = current.next
        current.prev.next = current.next
        current.next.prev = current.prev
        self.__size -= 1
        return current.val```
````

Comment: The name mangling caused by all those double underscores is causing this code not to work at all. Please test your code to make sure we can get to at least the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- `newest = Node(val)` should be `newest = self.__Node(val)` -- the code cannot parse otherwise
- `append_element` does not set the `prev` and `next` attributes of `newest` to the surrounding nodes, which is the main reason for errors you got.

Not a problem, but:

- in `insert_element_at` it is not necessary to do `if current is None`. The first `index` check already prevents that condition from occurring.
- in `insert_element_at` you could allow `index` to be equal to the list's size, in which case `append_element` would be called.
- you could add a `__get_element_at` method, so it can be called in `insert_element_at` and `remove_element` to avoid repetition of similar looping code.

I would put some more logic in the `__Node` constructor, so it can take the node before which the new node should be inserted. If provided it can take care of the "wiring". A `remove` method on `__Node` could then also take care of the "wiring" to remove a node from its surrounding list. This way all the wiring-code is concentrated in the `__Node` class.

Here is your code updated along those points:

```
class Linked_List:
    
    class __Node:
        def __init__ (self, val, before=None):
            self.val = val
            self.next = before
            self.prev = before and before.prev
            if before:
                if before.prev:
                    before.prev.next = self
                before.prev = self

        def extract(self):
            if self.next:
                self.next.prev = self.prev
            if self.prev:
                self.prev.next = self.next
            return self.val

    def __init__(self):
        self.__size = 0
        self.__trailer = self.__Node(None)
        self.__header = self.__Node(None, self.__trailer)
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.__size
    
    def append_element(self, val):
        self.__Node(val, self.__trailer)
        self.__size += 1

    def __get_element_at(self, index):
        if not (0 <= index < self.__size):
            raise IndexError
        current = self.__header.next
        for i in range(index):
            current = current.next
        return current
    
    def insert_element_at(self, val, index):
        if index == self.__size:
            return self.append_element(val)
        self.__Node(val, self.__get_element_at(index))
        self.__size += 1
        
    def remove_element_at(self, index):
        val = self.__get_element_at(index).extract()
        self.__size -= 1
        return val
```